# Apache: Multiple ProxyPassReverse, Multiple ServerNames, Single vhost

Tags: apache, nginx, vhosts

I am working on a particular set-up as follows:

- Several applications in multiple hosts and different ports
- A server (assume balancer.local) running nginx listening on port 8080 for localhost, which acts as a proxy/load balancer for the applications running on the previous hosts
- An apache2 server running on the same machine as nginx, listening on port 80 (open to the public), serving some contents directly for some `ServerName` and forwarding some other `ServerName` to `localhost:8080`, to let nginx do the load balancing work

The problem I have is that the number of hostnames to be redirected to nginx is growing fast, and I have an annoying list of vhosts which is becoming hard to maintain.

So, the question is: Is there a way I can define a default vhost in apache, without ServerNames, and make it redirect all the traffic which has not matched any other vhost to localhost:8080?

I already tried removing the `ServerName` directive, but the problem I have is that then ProxyPassReverse inserts its `hostname` into the outgoing URL.

At the moment, the only thing I was able to do is to reduce the number of rows in each vhost to the minimum, but it's still too much.

Here you have some configuration examples:

Nginx:

```
upstream foo {
        server foo1.local:9999 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server foo2.local:9999 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

upstream bar {
        server bar1.local:8888 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server bar2.local:8888 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}
server {
        listen *:8080;
        server_name  foo.public.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/foo.public.com-access.log  proxy;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/foo.public.com-error.log;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://foo/;
                include            /etc/nginx/proxy_app.conf;
        }
}
server {
        listen *:8080;
        server_name  bar.public.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/bar.public.com-access.log  proxy;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/bar.public.com-error.log;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://bar/;
                include            /etc/nginx/proxy_app.conf;
        }
}
```

Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName foo.public.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/nginx-redirect.sis.service-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/nginx-redirect.sis.service-access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse        /       http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName bar.public.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/nginx-redirect.sis.service-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/nginx-redirect.sis.service-access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse        /       http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName baz.public.com
    DocumentRoot /some/local/path
    <Directory "/">
      some irrelevant options
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In this example there are only two vhosts forwarded into nginx, but in my real set-up there's more than 30!

As I said, I already tried to use a single vhost without the `ServerName` tag to forward the traffic, but I ended up obtaining http://balancer.local/some/path in my redirections, which obviously didn't work.

I also tried to use a single `ServerName` and multiple `ServerAlias`, but in that case, ProxyPassReverse used always the ServerName in the response.

Any suggestion?

Comment: > I also tried to use a single ServerName and multiple ServerAlias, but in that case, ProxyPassReverse used always the ServerName in the response.

Do you have `UseCanonicalName On` somwhere in Apache config?

Comment: @alexeyten: Touché! Actually I had the opposite, `UseCanonicalName Off`, in my httpd.conf, but it seems that it was somehow ignored or simply not enough. So, I made it explicit inside my `VirtualHost`and that made the trick! Please convert your comment into a full answer (suggest setting the value explicitly to `Off`) and I will accept it as the valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried to use a single ServerName and multiple ServerAlias, but in that case, ProxyPassReverse used always the ServerName in the response.

Probably you have `UseCanonicalName On` somewhere in your Apache config.

Try to set it `Off` explicitly in your VirtualHost.